# Calculate Percentage from two colums and write back to table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

With a temporary table as:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    CDA     varchar(60),
    Found       int default 0,
    Accepted    int default 0,
    Percentage  decimal(3,0) default 0.0,
)
```

How do you take populated Found and Accepted columns and write it back to the Pecentage column?

I have:

```
UPDATE @Results SET Percentage = (
    SELECT (((Accepted * 1.00) / Found) * 100) FROM @Results 
)
```

Which if you take the SELECT line (comment out the UPDATE) it returns the correct values. However in the context of the UPDATE it fails with `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.`

**How do I write the values back to the correct row?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Result
   SET Percentage = Accepted / Found * 100
```

It won't work though with FOUND and ACCEPTED defined as INT, use cast when dividing or declare them with the same type as PERCENTAGE.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! However it is a moot point as I ended up calculating the percentage in reporting services via an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need a where clause, e.g. (untested)

```
UPDATE Result oResult
  SET Percentage = (SELECT Accepted / Found * 100
                      FROM Result iResult 
                     WHERE iResult.cda = oResult.cda);
```

However, if this is calculated you may wish not to have this as a column and just add it to any queries instead.  Note, most databases have a percent function.

Comment: I thought about the query but why complicate the query (this will becomea stored procedure) when I can hide the complexity here?

Comment: It gives Invalid Syntax for oResult. Tried both equals and AS and neither works.

Comment: What database are you using?  Works on oracle here.  

> but why complicate the query (this will becomea stored procedure) when I can hide the complexity here?
Because you know the data will be correct and you are not relying on your procedure having been called each time you update a value.

Comment: Appears you are not allowed to Alias Tables in update statements.

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to a SQL Server and never used it.  The following works on mysql 

UPDATE Result oResult LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT Accepted / Found * 100 AS pc, cda
  FROM Result) as iResult
 on iResult.cda = oResult.cda
 SET oResult.Percentage = iResult.pc;

Comment: Looking at that it won't work because MS-SQL Server doesn't allow aliasing of tables in update statements.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with sql server, try googling for correlated subqueries with ms sql server, a few possible solutions turned up but i can't try them